# Laravel Eloquent - Order by Enum Field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, enums, eloquent

I need to order my results by the `enum` field. This field, called `status` can be either `open`, `close`, or `edit`. Now, I want to get all the entries, with `edit`, then `open`, and finally `close` order.

Is this possible with Laravel Eloquent? I tried this (which sounds ridiculous, but I thought I'd give it a try), and didn't work:

```
Survey::orderBy('status', 'edit', 'open', 'close')->get();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
Survey::orderByRaw("FIELD(status, \"edit\", \"open\", \"close\")")->get();
```

Comment: Thats work for me thanx alot +1

Answer (score 3):

For postgres try this:

```
Survey::orderByRaw("case status when 'edit' then 1 when 'open' then 2 when 'close' then 3 end")->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If we have `asc` and `desc` both direction, please use below approach.

```php
$priorities = ['high', 'medium', 'low'];

if ($request->get('order_direction', "asc") === "desc") {
    $priorities = array_reverse($priorities);
}
$priorityString = implode('","', $priorities);

$query->orderByRaw('FIELD(priority, "' . $priorityString . '")');
```

Query it fires for `desc` order

```sql
select * from table order by FIELD(priority, "low","medium","high")
```

Query it fires for `asc` order

```sql
select * from table order by FIELD(priority, "high","medium","low")
```